# Change size of array depending on how many items are in it

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Okay, so I am making a calculator. You know how in a calculator, after you hit the plus, minus, etc. buttons, you can enter a new number. I am trying to do this with an array. Every time the user presses the "Enter" button, the number in the textbox will be added to the array. The array will then be summed to have a total of all numbers in the array.

Since the user can enter as many numbers as they want, I assume I have to use a dynamic array.

Is there a way to shrink the array so that the length is the number of items in the array?

Here is how I have my array declared:

```
Dim inputNumbers() As Double = New Double() {}
```

And here is how I am trying to resize it. I am trying to count how many items are in the array (which is held in the `intItems` variable. I then try to redeclare the array by using `intItems` as the number of array elements.

```
 Dim intItems As Integer
    intItems = UBound(inputNumbers)
    ReDim inputNumbers(intItems)

    For i As Integer = 0 To inputNumbers.Length - 1
        inputNumbers(i) = CDbl(inputTxt.Text)
    Next i
```

This is the code I have for the enter button. Since there will be a number, the array should start with 1 item in it when this button is pressed. so it should be inputNumbers(0) meaning there is 1 item in it.

This program will output the sum of the array as 0 currently. When running the debugger, it skips over the for loop because when it gets to it, the for loop starts at `For i as Integer = 0 to 0` so it doesnt run.

So right now, I do not know what to do. I tried just making the array hold 999 items at the start but that makes the output display wrong information.

So my question is how to make it so the array length is set to be the number of elements inside of it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would suggest you use a `List(Of Double) and not concern yourself with this sort of memory micromanagement.

Comment: Obvios XY problem. Main problem is -> needs in dynamic collection, selected solution -> is array, question -> how to change size of array. Real answer on the main problem is `List(Of Double)` as @ZevSpitz pointed out already.

Comment: doesn't seem like you need array at all, just a variable to store the result.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an array, where you have to manage the size of the array, you can use a `List(Of Double)`, which manages its own size:

```
Dim numbers As New List(Of Double)
```

Then, when <kbd>ENTER</kbd> is pressed:

```
numbers.Add(inputText.Text) 'you may need a CDbl here
```

---

Unrelated, but whether you are using an array or a list, when you want to calculate the sum, you can use LINQ:

```
Dim sum = numbers.Sum
```

---

If you must use an array for some reason, note that your code is never increasing the size of the array (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40582319/) answer); you're `ReDim`ming your array to the current size of the array.

Moreover, you should use `Redim Preserve` so you don't have to copy the contents of the old array to the new array.

Answer (score -1):

```
Redim Preserve inputNumbers(inputNumbers.GetUpperBound(0) + 1) 'Increase the capacity of the array by one
inputNumbers(inputNumbers.GetUpperBound(0)) = CDbl(inputTxt.Text)
```